# Search a NSArray filled with JSON for a specific title

Tags: ios, xcode, json, nsarray, nspredicate

I'm working on my first serious iphone app and using json for the first time.
Now i have a searchfield above my tableview, and i want to filter the data to the entered search text. The JSON looks like this:

```
{
"id":1,
"title":"Een Product",
"category":"Categorie",
"description":"Een Beschrijving",
"price":"10.00",
"image":"http:\/\/dev.smit-it.info\/APP\/LOGO\/een.png"
},
```

and now i want to able to search by title, i am trying the following.

```
- (void) searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)sender
{
    [self.SearchbarOnDisplay resignFirstResponder];
    self.SearchbarOnDisplay.showsCancelButton=NO;

    //ToDo:Get the search results
    NSString *match = self.SearchbarOnDisplay.text;

    self.SearchIsStarted = YES;

    NSPredicate *sPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF CONTAINS[cd] %@", match];
    NSArray *ArrayWithFilteredContent;

    ArrayWithFilteredContent = [self.dynamicData.DynamicRetrevedData filteredArrayUsingPredicate:sPredicate];
    [self.tableView reloadData];

}
```

now i set some breakpoints and the problem is that `self.dynamicData.DynamicRetrevedData` is NIL. what i don't understand because this is alloc and init in the viewdidload and the data is currently showed in the tableview. And if it was not nil how do i specify that it searches for title.

Hope you can help, i'm already trying this for 2 day's

Comment: If some of you rather want the project am happy to share it

Comment: Will be easier with project itself or at least paste the code for viewDidLoad so we can see where and how you allocate stuff.

Comment: what is `self.dynamicData.DynamicRetrevedData` ?? first check it in NSLog before NSPredicate

Comment: if you keep a JSON inside DynamicRetrevedData you need to deserialize it first to NSDictonary* and than predicate with each value in it. Check NSJSONSerialization for that.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/4rjbnh3a3au1nx9/Smit%20IT.zip, checked it in a log but it doesn't log so i assume it is nil.

Comment: Note i'm using xcode 5 GM and IOS 7. Don't know if that matters to you!

Comment: @Grzegorz i deserialize in my datamodel. So thats already done. but thanks for your comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First things is that your pattern of `NSPredicate` is not right, it should be

```
NSPredicate *sPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"title CONTAINS[cd] %@", match]; // or @"title beginswith[c] %@" for alphabetically search.
```

But it is not other issue. first check code line by line if your tableView's data is properly display then it should be working `self.dynamicData.DynamicRetrevedData`